# Why is it undefined if multiple threads join a thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

If I have multiple threads and I would like to wait for a thread to finish, why is this undefined according to the pthread_join() function?

For example, the code below shows thread 1 and 2 wait for thread 0:

```
void* thread1(void* t1){
..
pthread_join(pthread_t thread0, void **retval1);
return NULL
}

void* thread2(void* t2){
..
pthread_join(pthread_t thread0, void **retval2);
return NULL
}
```

Why would this behaviour be undefined or in other words not possible?

Comment: I think this example needs code, because you seem to have a misconception here. The joining of two threads is not a symmetric operation. I.e. it is fine if thread A1 joins B, and then thread A2 joins B. That means B waits for A1 to finish,and then waits for A2 to finish. What won't work is having B1 and B2 both wait for thread A to finish.

Comment: The latter case is the is what I am referring to. I will include code to illustrate this.

Comment: BTW, note that POSIX also makes it impossible for thread B to wait on `A1 and A2` or `A1 or A2`. You have to wait on `A1` and then wait on `A2`, which is a bit of a hassle if you don't know up from which one will finish first. In comparison, Windows has `WaitForMultipleObjects`. This is _far_ more flexible.

Comment: @MSalters I am aware that threads can only wait on one thread in linux but what I don't understand is why multiple threads cannot wait on one thread to finish. What is  stopping them from doing so?

Comment: Are you asking why you can't call pthread_join twice, or are you asking for a way to accomplish what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pthread_`t object will generally point to some allocated data pertaining to the thread. Among this data will generally be the return value of the thread. `pthread_join` will read the return value and free the thread data.

If you `pthread_join` the same pthread id twice, you kind of have a case of a double-free. The pointed to data might be invalid on the second join, but it also could have been reused in an unpredictable fashion by another thread.

The results are difficult/impossible to reason about. Hence the UB.

Comment: To avoid such an issue why not place it in the stack?

Comment: @duper21: Place what in what stack?

Comment: @duper21 A thread needs a stack of its own. You can only fit so many stacks in a stack and stack-allocated thread data would be invalidated the moment the pthread_create-caller  (pthread_create would additionally need to be a macro, otherwise it wouldn't be able to allocate stack data in its "caller") returned. Threads should be heap allocated (or equivalent).

Comment: @PSkocik Would it be correct to say that the return value must be available to other threads hence must be placed in the heap which is why the issue of 'double-frees' might arise?

Comment: @duper21: _which_ stack? `thread0` won't have a stack after `thread1` does the join, so `thread2` still fails. And up front C won't know that `thread1` will be doing the join, so it can't use that stack either.

Comment: @duper21 Most importantly, a thread needs a stack and the heap is about the most convenient place to put a new stack on. The tiny space for the return value can be conveniently allocated with it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `retval` of `thread0` is stored until *one* thread calls `pthread_join`. After that, the `retval` is no longer available.

C++ has `std::shared_future` which explicitly is designed so multiple threads can wait for a single result, which shows your idea isn't strange.

Comment: If it is included in C++ why is it not available in C?

Comment: @duper21: C++ has destructors, so it's easy to keep track of how many `std::shared_future` instances are waiting for a result. C can't keep track of how many `pthread_t` values still exist.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_join` is a resource-identifier-freeing operation, like `close` on file descriptors, `free` on allocated memory, `unlink` on filenames, etc. All such operations are inherently subject to "double-free"/"use-after-free" bugs if the identifier (here, the particular pattern of bits making up the `pthread_t` value) can be used again in the future. As such, the behavior has to be either completely undefined or subject to conditions that make it a serious programming error, to the point where it might as well be undefined.

Note that in your mental model you might be thinking of both `pthread_join` calls "starting before the thread exits", and thereby taking place during the time when the `pthread_t` identifier is still valid. However formally there is no ordering between them, nor can there be. There is no observable distinction between the state of "already blocked in `pthread_join`" and "just about to call `pthread_join`".